# How to get updated server files from elastic beanstalk?

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am hosting my server for my website on AWS Elastic beanstalk. On my server I am storing files that are getting uploaded by end users (or myself) in an "Images" folder. Thus new files are getting created in the folder every time an image gets uploaded to the website.

How can i download the latest file of my server on E.B. with these new images. I can download the original zip file I uploaded but it doesn't have the new data in the folders.

TY

Answer (score 0):

You should not be storing any files worth anything on the EB node.
if user uploads content, you should be uploading that in turn to S3, or your DB, or any kind of file storage. That is usually decided during architecture.

So while the actual answer is "**this should never happened in the first place**", I must precise the main reason is that auto-scaling can kill your nodes without you knowing. which would destroy the uploads. or bring new nodes, spreading your content through multiple nodes.

While I also understand this answer might not be helping you if you already done the mistake have content to be transfered out of the node. I would

1. disable autoscaling
2. enable termination protection on the node
3. transfer data via rsync/ssh/s3 or favorite different options by SSH
4. automate transfer method to be done a subsequent time.
5. implement new upload method for the future of your app
6. deploy new method so no new content is uploaded to previous storage location
7. re-transfer your date from old to new storage location.
8. disable termination protection and reenable autoscaling
9. make sure new nodes and receiving traffic and why not kill that previous node
10. remember servers are cattle not pets